# A problem in spectroscopy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spectroscopy

[image]
In this problem the wavelengths of emission are not equispaced. The answer is given as rigid rotator. We can write the energy as E=BJ(J+1) where J=0,1,2 etc. In order to justify the answer as rigid rotator I have to consider transitions from J=1,2,3 level to J=0. But isn't it violating the transition laws ∆J=J+1 or ∆J=J-1?

Comment: why do you only consider transitions to the ground states?   Also rotational bands often decay through quadrupole interaction for which $\Delta J=0,\pm 1,\pm 2$ are possible.

Comment: I was considering dipole interactions only. That is why the energy levels were equispaced.  But the quadrupole interactions justify the answer.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.